# How to extract digits after a comma

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that contains a two decimal number

I would like to extract the two decimals

for example in my case I would like 70 to be returned to me

```
cccc=Number (bbb) + Number (aaa) + Number (ccc) ;
//cccc=145.70
duree=cccc;
DernierChiffre = cccc.substring(cccc.length-2, cccc.length); 
console.log(DernierChiffre);
```

Comment: You can use toFixed native method: `number.toFixed(2)`

Comment: `Math.round(145.70 * 100) % 100` is `70`